# How does my app recognize that a song finished?

Tags: iphone, xcode, avaudioplayer

I´m working on my first app. It plays an mp3 song. Everything works fine, but I need the app to recognize that the sound finished, then change the button “pause” image to the “play” one. I can already do that, but just when the button is pressed, not when song ends.

Another issue is that when the song restarts after stop->play, it doesn´t continue playing at the previous volume setting (got a slider). The player starts at maximum volume. I can change the volume slider position, but I am not able to make the app respect the set volume when restarts.

Any help will be very appreciated!
Thnx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When using "AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol delegate", please do not forget to set delegate (for example) as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"33fr" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSError *error = nil;

    myPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];

    if (error) {
         NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
         return;
         }

    [myPlayer setDelegate:self]; <<=== HERE!

}
```

I uploaded sample code here.  Please check it. ->
http://yahoo.jp/box/X7Hxfk

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation, and of course for uploading your example. Unfortunately, I couldn´t make it work for my project. Is there anything like private, where I can send my project to you, so you can kindly give it a look? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did not use any private libraries, so please check version of your X code if it is 4.5.2 or later.
Or please just add "//" before "<<=== HERE!".

I believe if you check and read the error message to find why you cannot make it work for your project, you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done much of Objective-C but it looks like you need to implement a delegate.

I quote: "You implement a delegate to handle interruptions (such as an incoming phone call) and to update the user interface when a sound has finished playing."

I am just reading the AVAudioPlayer Class Reference here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067

Comment: Thnks a lot, i saw this, but it´s not what I was looking for. I need to detect a song stopped playing in order to change some settings of my player, like button images, volumes, etc…

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol delegate`

> After the audio player is finished playing the song (if it does so
>   successfully), the audio PlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully: delegate
>   method will be called in the delegate object of the audio player. We
>   can implement this method like below (this method is defined in the
>   AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol):

```
 - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player  successfully:(BOOL)flag
{ 
   if (flag)
{   
 NSLog(@"Audio player stopped correctly.");
  } 
else 
{    NSLog(@"Audio player did not stop correctly."); 
 }  
  if ([player isEqual:self.audioPlayer])
{    self.audioPlayer = nil; 
 }
 else
 {    /* This is not the player */  }
  }
```

in .h file add delegate like below code

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried, but it´s not working. Remember I´m very new at this. It happens too that my AVAudioPlayer is declared as audioPlayer in the h. So may this conflict the code? I just copied and pasted the code in my m. Anything else I should do? Thnx again…

Comment: in .h file add  <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>